# ASP .NET,concurrency control with WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, nhibernate, concurrency

I would like to take advise from all of you based on your experience with SOA based architecture and how to achieve concurrency control with WCF and nHibernate.

1. ASP .NET (web app) - 1 tier (Web server)
2. WCF+nHibernate - 2nd tier (Application server)

### Scenario1

a. User1 has now opened an Order and Edits it.
b. User2 in meantime opens the same Order and Edits it.

How do we prevent User2 from performing this operation. Both WCF calls to "edit order" fetches the record using different nHibernate sessions as the application server is designed to be stateless.

How do I configure nHibernate/WCF to handle this kind of scenario?

### Scenario2

If entering an order involves multiple pages; with pages getting displayed based on business logic (WCF calls to determine next page) should the order data be maintained at Web Server (ASP .NET) across these pages and posted on each WCF call taking care of the order business logic? Is my thinking right?

I'm aware of the other way to do it, which is to create a temporary order record to maintain intermediate data across pages/WCF calls.

Comment: First problem is solved by pessimistic and optimistic concurrency, not by wcf

Comment: May I know how does it happen when the nHibernate sessions are different? The order data is just returned and session closed. The UI enabled the page to be editable. Yes I agree while saving the same order concurrently a lock is imposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to the first scenario, you don't want to block the user from attempting to make an edit; your system will never scale if you try and enforce pessimistic concurrency.

Rather, you want to use optimistic concurrency; your models would have a timestamp (usually an actual date time value, or better yet, some sort of binary value guaranteed to be unique for the particular context/table).  Most ORMs (including nHibernate, I am sure) have support for optimistic concurrency; when generating the update, it will only update the record if the primary key is the same *and* the timestamp are the same, if it isn't, then you know that someone else edited the record since the last time you fetched the data.

For your second scenario, you might want to consider [Windows Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328), which has tight integration with WCF.  Generally though, I'd have a *separate table* which contains the incomplete order information along with a key that the user can use (perhaps the session id) to look up the data.

Only when you know the order is complete do you move the data from your "staging" table over to your real orders table.

Comment: Thanks CasperOne. It answers my question.

Comment: @GeorgeKT: No problem, it's what we're here for =)

Comment: I have one more question on my mind, in the second scenario, what if I don't want to use WWF and staging table.... because its a simple order entry page with next->next page capturing user confirmation and finally captures credit card info before the order is complete. So would the approach to maintain the order data across pages be taken care by the order page developer at the web server level good? Do you foresee any drawbacks?

Comment: I'm envisioning it like this - a single ASP .NET page with order entry data maintained on post backs and displaying different sections on the same page (virtually end use perceives it as different pages) based on business logic responses from WCF (application server)

Comment: @GeorgeKT: You don't need WW for the order management, but if you have a long time between pages (say a person could leave the order in an unfinished state for days) then it's something you should look at.  I strongly recommend a staging approach; if you don't, you run the risk of loosening constraints or adding data in the orders data store (tables) which don't belong there.  You want to keep your database as encapsulated and well-defined as your code.